# Manga where the female lead dies alone and returns to the past

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Trying to find a manga where the female lead is kicked out of the house after her husband dies and has no money. She goes back in time and tries to make money by making lace and candles before they’re in style. She spends less money and has a better relationship with her husband who I think is a duke. She clears up the miscommunication with her brother and dad whom she thought had abandoned her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall any character or place names or any notable aspects of the art?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the female lead's hair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[The Marriage Business](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-marriage-business)*.

> Bianca de Blanche was the wife of Zakari de Arno, but **after his death, she was thrown out of the Arno family for luxury and immorality**. After wandering nowhere to the fall of her father, the Blanche family, she is driven to a shabby periphery monastery. And at the end, she eventually died on the cold stone floor. A villainess who doesn't know the honor. That was the life before Bianca's return....

The story opens with the main character in a monastery, praying to god for a second chance. She dies on the floor, having been in bad health, and wakes up in the past when her husband was still alive, and she was still living as a hated, spendthrift wife.

The lace scene happens immediately after reincarnating.

[image: Creating lace before it's popular]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag combination `Marriage` and `Time Rewind`.